# PHP Mysql Insert doesn't work at Firefox only

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, mysqli

I have a page with a form where it is inserted name, project, etc ... When I click on submit form Firefox or IE does not work, however Chrome does work normally.

OBS:

1- I had an old DB. When I change this to the old DB address the insert works in both browsers.

2- I have another page that update to the data and works normally for all browsers, the problem is just inserting data using IE and Firefox.

3- I am using a library for db php mysql: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Would the problem be in the code, DB or in the browser?

```
function action_adddb () {
    global $db;

    $data = Array(
        'prname' => $_POST['prname'],
        'members' => $_POST['members']
    );

    $id = $db->insert ('users', $data);


    header ("Location: page_insert.php");
    exit;
}

$db = new Mysqlidb ('nomedohost', 'username', 'senha', 'nomedobanco');
if ($_GET) {
    $f = "action_".$_GET['action'];
    if (function_exists ($f)) {
        $f();
    }
}


<form name ="form1" class=" form-horizontal" action='page_insert.php?action=<?php echo $action?>' method=post>

<input type=hidden name='id' value='<?php echo $data['id']?>'>

<input class="form-control" type=text name='prname' required placeholder='Project Name' value="<?php echo $data['prname']?>">
<input class="form-control" type=text name='members' required placeholder='Members (First and Middle name)' value='<?php echo $data['members']?>'>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Create"  class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-block">

</form>
```

Comment: I think it might be the `client side`, If we may, can you add the `js code` in your question?

Comment: As stated by @eeya, server code is always browser independant. So your problem should come from your JS instead.

Comment: I've used a construct like this before, but I wonder if the browsers are messing it up: `action='page_insert.php?action=<?php echo $action?>' method=post>`  IOW, is the browser sending both GET and POST or is it dropping one?  Something to check...